# checking a variable as a number

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am writing a discord bot and I have a variable. Users query the license plate with this command Ex.(!qq TR 34)

I just want the plate to check the number entry, if a letter or special character is entered ex.(!qq TR 34ü,)
and error to the user please do not use special characters or letters how can I do it

```
if (countryID.length < 1)
        return message.channel.sendEmbed(usageCommand);
    else if (plaque.length == countryID.length)
        return message.channel.sendEmbed(usageCommand);
else
```

Comment: how about isInteger(variable) ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger

Comment: isNaN has done my job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

burcu.

NaN Errors occur when a string that cannot be a number is made into a number.

You can determine whether the entered string can be converted to a number.

[Docs - isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN)

ex

```js
isNaN('34')     // false;
isNaN('34ü')    // true;
```